# BIND 9.16.1 delays in responding to queries

Tags: networking, dns

Newly installed BIND9 DNS server (Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS) is experiencing persistent delays in its service. They're of two different kinds, but presumed to be interlinked.

1. Running dig with any existing domain name, being never 'dug' there before, on the server, I obtain an answer with anomalous delay of 5000 ms (i.e. 5 seconds).
2. Windows clients in the local subnet, served by the ISC DHCP server v4, state that they can't access to the Internet, 'cause DNS server isn't responding. Running nslookup on them gives me a constant 'DNS request timed out'.
   Note 1: BIND is set up as a caching server, so the following statements are present in its options:
   recursion yes;
   allow-query { intranet; };
   allow-recursion { intranet; };
   Note 2: IPFilter (iptables) is set to ACCEPT policy, NAT masquerading is explicitly set, packets forwarding is uncommented in sysctl.conf and set to '1'.
   Note 3: 'intranet' from Note 1 is defined as an ACL for encompassing a local 192.168.0.0/23 subnet and localhost.

Can anyone tell me what the damned thing I've missed or misconfigured?

P.S. The 'neighboring' DNS server on Zentyal 6.2 works fine with the same ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting `qname-minimization` to either `strict` or `disabled`.

The behavior of the default setting (`relaxed`) appears to have changed subtly somewhere around bind-9.15, which caused some of my DNS clients' queries to be delayed by the cache to the point where the client just gave up waiting for a response.